# GNU make wildcard no longer gives sorted output. Is there any control switch?

Tags: makefile, wildcard, gnu-make

The wildcard function returns sorted results in version 3.81, but it does do that in version 4.2. Is there any compile/runtime switch to control this fucntion?

Below shows the results from two version of GNU make.

```
$ ls
a.mk  a0.svp  a1.svp  a2.svp  a3.svp  a4.svp  a5.svp  a6.svp  a7.svp  a8.svp  a9.svp

$ cat a.mk 
SVP_FILES := $(wildcard *.svp)

all:
        @echo $(SVP_FILES)

$ make  -f a.mk all          
a0.svp a1.svp **a2.svp a3.svp a4.svp a5.svp a6.svp a7.svp a8.svp a9.svp**

$ ~/sandbox/bin/make  -f a.mk all          
a0.svp a1.svp **a6.svp a5.svp a9.svp a4.svp a3.svp a2.svp a7.svp a8.svp**

$make –v | head -n 1

GNU Make 3.81

$ ~/sandbox/bin/make -v | head -n 1

GNU Make 4.2
```

Answer (score 21):

As mentioned in the [NEWS](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/NEWS) file

> Version 3.82 (28 Jul 2010)
>
> [...]
>
> - WARNING: Backward-incompatibility!
>     Wildcards were not documented as returning sorted values, but the results
>     have been sorted up until this release..  If your makefiles require sorted
>     results from wildcard expansions, use the `$(sort ...)`  function to request
>     it explicitly.

I.e. `SVP_FILES := $(sort $(wildcard *.svp))`

Answer (score 4):

GNU make 4.3 has sorted globs again.

In https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?52076

It turned out, that nobody knew why the sorting was dropped.